# Generic Relation not reflecting in migrations in django?

Tags: python, django, architecture

I'm trying to add a `GenericRelation` field to the `Notification` model to my `Bond` model. The issue is that whenever I run `makemigrations`, this field does not get acknowledged. What could be the issue?

Error:

> django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Field 'content_object' does not generate an automatic reverse relation and therefore cannot be used for reverse querying. If it is a GenericForeignKey, consider adding a GenericRelation.

```py
class Bond(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    follower = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="follower")
    bond_created = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    notifications = GenericRelation(Notification)
```

```py
class Notification(models.Model):

    #337, 777, 765, 843, 124
    notification_type = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Comment: also see docs for [reverse generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#reverse-generic-relations)

Answer (score 0):

Try to place the Notification model above the Bond model in models.py.
I can't say that it will solve the problem,but you can try.
And if this also not work,try to first delete all new fields then do makemigrations migrate then again add those new fields and do makemigrations and migrate.
Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding unique `related_query_name` for related model and see.

```
notifications = GenericRelation(Notification, related_query_name='bond')
```